# How can I show a card only if its content is different than empty on angular?

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to create a ngIf on angular that shows me a card only if it is different than empty. This is the code I have so far:

```
  <div class="container mb-4" *ngFor='let item of listaUsuario'>
      <div class="card">
        <h2>{{item.nomeStartUp}}</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Using this code above, it shows me all the items on this array, but some of them are empty, and I don't want to see them, so I tried using this ngIf on the code to hide the empty items:

```
  <div class="container mb-4" *ngFor='let item of listaUsuario'>
     <div *ngIf="{{item.nomeStartUp}} !== null ">
      <div class="card">
        <h2>{{item.nomeStartUp}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but sadly it wont work, could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Below should help

```
  <div class="container mb-4" *ngFor='let item of listaUsuario'>
     <div *ngIf="item.nomeStartUp">
      <div class="card">
        <h2>{{item.nomeStartUp}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

if item.nomeStartup is an array then you should try this

```
  <div class="container mb-4" *ngFor='let item of listaUsuario'>
     <div *ngIf="item.nomeStartUp.length">
      <div class="card">
        <h2>{{item.nomeStartUp}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note: inside *ngIf you don't need double curly brackets for mentioning the variables.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much sir, i didn't know that i dont really need to use the double curly brackets for the ngIf.